# How to parse JSON in haskell

Tags: haskell-stack, parsec, aeson

I need to parse a JSON incoming form the UI into a data structure.
the data structure is a combination of other data structures

```
Data Collection = Collection { t1 :: t1 , t2::t2}
newtype t1 = t1 {unt1 :: String}
data t2 = t2 {id :: Integer, rank :: String}
```

The data I am getting is in the format

```
{
  "t1": {
    "_unt1": "at1Value"
  },
  "t2": {
    "id" : 1
   "rank": "Officer"
 }
}
```

I basically need to create a Collection Data type . How should I do this in the simplest way ?

I tried the Aeson library and made Collection and instance of JSON ,and then tried something like

```
decode data :: Maybe Collection
```

But that doesn't work. I did try looking into the parsec library as well, But I am not sure whether that will be useful here.

I am pretty new to haskell, so maybe I am missing something here. What would be the best way to implement this taking into consideration the actual data structure might be much more complicated than the example I gave, with it going several layers deep

Answer (score 0):

import Text.JSON.Generic  and decode the json.

```
import           Text.JSON.Generic

................

decodeJSON data :: Collection
```